# 2D Java Terrain Generator

Tags: java, 2d, terrain

How can I form islands randomly in my 2D game? I have no idea how to start out!

```
void generateMap()
{
    blocks.clear();
    for(int x = 0; x < 150; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 150; y++)
        {
            if(Math.random() < 0.5)
                blocks.add(new Block(x * Block.blockSize, y * Block.blockSize, eBlockType.GRASS));
            else
                blocks.add(new Block(x * Block.blockSize, y * Block.blockSize, eBlockType.WATER));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Stackoverflow does not like minecraft.. sorry :(

Answer (score 5):

You are getting bad results because you are randomly generating each terrain block.
Instead, you probably want to take previously generated blocks into account, in order to form *almost real* islands.

You should probably take a look at [Perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) or [Simplex noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise) algorithms. See also [this article](https://code.google.com/p/fractalterraingeneration/wiki/Simplex_Noise), which explains algorithm in detail.